# If I want to learn how to administrate a web server which option will be easier?

Tags: web-server

Which option will be easier to administrate Linux server or Windows server (for web platform)?

Also which one will cost me more if I choose managed hosting instead of learning how to manage it myself?

Comment: Which are you most familiar with, Windows or Linux? It's usually a good idea to stick with what you are most comfortable with.

Comment: None of them; I am asking about the easiest?

Comment: Queue Windows people shouting "Windows" and Linux people shouting "Linux" in 3, 2, 1....

Answer (score 3):

The easiest one to administer is whichever one you're most familiar with.  If you have no clue about either, then you should use whichever one your mentor is most familiar with.  If you have no mentor... flip a coin maybe?

Practically speaking, you should run whichever OS your application will work best on.  If you don't have an application, you don't need a server yet.

All things being equal (which they never are), Windows will be a more expensive option for managed hosting *or* doing it yourself, because it has licence fees which Linux doesn't.  In practice, the costs will vary far more based on the quality of the provider and their actual level of service than which operating system you choose.